# Passing computed value to form with angular

Tags: javascript, angular

When I change the value in club dropdown, the ID visually changes, but nothing gets passed into my form. I keep getting null when try to insert the value from ID box to a table. Would appreciate any help

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>id</label>
  <div class="form-control" name="club_api_id" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="form.club_api_id">
    <tr *ngFor="let obj of klubbid" [value]="obj.id">{{obj.id}} </tr>
  </div>
```

This is how it look like:

[image: this is how it look like locally]

Comment: you look like you're trying to implement some kind of custom form here. that carries some overhead work to do. or you can make life easy and use a standard input element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @bryan60 https://imgur.com/PIF9YCG this is what it look like with input. it still wont pass the value into my form. still getting null.

Comment: i can't do much with screenshots of screens. need to see the code where you're trying to use an actual input element

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a few issues with the position where your form object is attached in the DOM.

1. You have attached the form to the div "club_api_id"; div elements are not going to update the form, as the user does not usually have a way to change its contents.
2. the "id" is not pegged to a form attribute at the moment, at least not from this part of the code you have shared. In this tr, the value of the id will be placed into the `tr`, but if the user changes it, it will not be placed into the form.

```
<tr *ngFor="let obj of klubbid" [value]="obj.id">{{obj.id}} </tr>
```

if you use a `select` instead of the `tr` and attach the form property to the value of this select, it should work:

```
<div class="form-control" name="club_api_id">
    <select  [(ngModel)]="form.club_api_id">
      <option *ngFor="let obj of klubbid" [value]="obj.id">{{obj.id}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: i did do this at first, but the problem is that ID doesnt auto update itself. Like visually the ID code change whenever i change to a new club. however the value that is passed to the form is the first selected value. Say i select club 1, ID will show  1 and get passed to form, all good, but now when i change to club 2, the ID will change to 2 visually, but what the form receive is 1. To change this the user must select Id self. which is why i tried to use TR, but that passed nothing to the form.

Comment: would you mind building a [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy) with the issue you see on using the select tag?